# is there a method to make randomly number in multi row?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make 4 rows with random number change every 1 second and the five-row make it with a stick number ( no change every 1 second ), and if I click on it the changes of 4 rows will be stopped.

i make a code for only 5 row like this
**5 4 6 3 1**

and its will be take more lines if i want put it like this
**5 4 6 3 1**
**1 6 1 3 6**
**3 2 4 6 8**
**4 2 1 7 8**

How can I do it with a better method and to minimize my code

[This is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/gLevh7cx/)

```
<html>

<table >
    <tbody>
        <tr id = 'tt2' style="font-size: 22px;">

        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  <script>





      var onerow2 = null;
    var onenumber2 = null;
    var numbersrandom2 = null;
    var count2 = 0;
    var done = false;
      function random2(){
        if (done == false){
            one = isit(onerow2,'one')     
            two = isit(onerow2,'two')  
            three = isit(onerow2,'three')  
            four = isit(onerow2,'four')  
            five = isit(onerow2,'five')         
             if (onerow2 == null){
                numbers = [one,two,three,four,five];
              numbersrandom2 = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
            isit2(numbersrandom2,one,'one')
            isit2(numbersrandom2,two,'two')
            isit2(numbersrandom2,three,'three')
            isit2(numbersrandom2,four,'four')
            isit2(numbersrandom2,five,'five')
        }
        var row = "<td onclick='selectroad(this);'  id='one'>" + one + "</td><td onclick='selectroad(this) ' id='two'>" + two + "</td><td onclick='selectroad(this) ' id='three'>" + three + "</td><td onclick='selectroad(this) ' id='four'>" + four + "</td><td onclick='selectroad(this) ' id='five'>" + five + "</td>"
        document.getElementById("tt2").innerHTML = row;         
        count2 = count2 + 1
        if (count2 == 15){
             onerow2 = null;
     onenumber2 = null;
     numbersrandom2 = null;
     count2 = 0
        }
        return numbersrandom2;
        }
      }


        function isit(i,t){
            if (i != t){
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1) 
        }else{
        return onenumber2
        }
        }
        function isit2(i,t,b){
            if (i == t){
            onerow2 = b;
            onenumber2 = numbersrandom2
        }
        }

      function selectroad(obj) {
        var id = obj.getAttribute("id");
        if (id == onerow2){

             done = true;
        }
      }


      function reload(){         
      setInterval(random2, 1000);         
      }
      reload();
      random2();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your "click->stop" task, so do it by yourself, but there is the main idea:

Create a table and store all it's rows and columns, then update it with `setInterval`

I've added the functionality to stop updating of the specified row and the specified column (add attribute `disabled` to the element)

```js
var table = initTable(document.getElementById("tbl"), 5, 5)

setInterval(update, 1000, table)

setTimeout(() => table.rows[3].element.attributes["disabled"] = "disabled", 3000) // example disable row updating

function initTable(table, rows, columns) {
  var rows = new Array(rows).fill().map(() => table.appendChild(document.createElement("tr")))
  return { element: table, rows: rows.map(row => ({ element: row, columns: new Array(columns).fill().map(() => row.appendChild(document.createElement("td")) )})) }
}

function update(table) {
  for(const row of table.rows)
    if(!row.element.attributes["disabled"])
       for(const column of row.columns)
          if(!column.attributes["disabled"])
            column.innerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)

}
```

```html
<table id="tbl" style="font-size: 22px;"></table>
```

Comment: can be 1 row in in every column have stick number * no change * like what i did and if i click on the stick number the row will stop and another row without affect * complete change * and if click another stick number it will stop like before, like what i did

Comment: @Mr.Exp yeah, exactly (if you run my example, the fourth row will be stopped after 3 sec). Just add the functionality to listen to the `click` events and stop add/remove `disabled` attributes where you want

Comment: there's no stick number in every row